# Error paper.js file in opera

Tags: opera, paperjs

I have some paperscript.
I install last version opera (12.0) and this version, not supports paperjs, in js error log of opera, writed this error message (error in file paper.js)

**Linked script compilation. Syntax error at line 7633 while loading: In string literal: unexpected end of script "\f";case"0":return"**

I downloaded file paper.js therefrom: http://paperjs.org/download/
in other browsers, my paperscript works and not errors, error only in opera. If someone know, please tell me, what the opera wants to?

Comment: Hi, do you have a link I could see this problem on? I tried http://paperjs.org/examples/ but it seems to work fine. Do you get the same error there?

Comment: What version opera have you? you tried this link in opera? in my opera this not working (I have opera 12.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by a bug in the browser.js file Opera automatically updates every three days or so. I pushed out a fix yesterday, so you should get it soon.
Further details on http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/

Sorry about the inconvenience and any grey hairs or scratched heads this caused you.

Comment: Thanks very much. and one question: You are one of the creators the opera browser ? 0_o

Comment: Yes, sort of :) I work for Opera doing QA - in other words testing, especially regarding broken sites, trying to figure out if the problem lies with Opera or the site, and what exactly is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, paperjs working in opera, thanks opera group.